# How about linking Stack Exchange to IFTTT?

Tags: feature-request, api

Why is there no channel for Stack Overflow on IFTTT?

It would be great if I can mash up the Stack Exchange website with other web-based services like Google Reader or GMail, receive a SMS or notifications, etc.

See https://ifttt.com/

Comment: After taking a good look at the IFTTT website, I have come to the conclusion that they have little or no intention of allowing third parties to write providers. Support for Stack Exchange would need to be implemented by the site developers.

Comment: did you try to contact them ?

Comment: I can do that :)

Comment: We can all suggest that IFTTT implement a new "Channel" for StackExchange. If many people do this, IFTTT might priorities the Channel. https://ifttt.com/help/channel_suggestion

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 6):

Actually this can be done with using the rss feed channel on ifttt. together with the rss feed from the **[Stack2rss app](http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/)** that transforms stackoverflow api queries to an rss feed.
like:

http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/users/{{your user id}}/questions?body=true

you should check the api for the specific query you like (respone, specific questions tag, your answers, another users answers etc) and then construct a query

Comment: stack2rss does work, but it only works with one individual SE site. It does not provide an RSS feed which covers all the StackExchange sites (e.g. https://stackexchange.com/users/$UID/ )

Comment: True,but that is the current situation.. I think (although) I didn't check. From what I can tell this is a limitation of the stackoverflow REST Api. since stack2rss is just a transformation tool from the json api to rss this can't be done with it. I think this handles most use cases.

Comment: Is this still supposed to work? http://stack2rss.stackexchange.com/ 404s for me…

Comment: Old answer.. don't know noe